# Odd Results when comparing C++ overhead on old/new CPU

Tags: c++, performance, containers, cpu

I have this C++ code which:

Generates 10000 initialised Students into a container.
Sorts the Students alphabetically.
Sorts the Students into passed and failed.
Outputs the results to console.

For efficiency, execution is timed using different containers types(both static and non-static) to hold & iterate the 10000 students.

Nothing is being read from files, all the student data is contained in the code.

Here is a benchmark comparison between the two CPUs being used, it should be obvious from the results that one is new and one is old:

http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i7-3770K-vs-AMD-Opteron-170#performance

Here are the results comparing execution times on each CPU....any idea why the new CPU is being left behind by the older cpu? :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
AMD Opteron 170 - STATIC VECTOR ( 10,000 students =  27.499 secs )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
gen_students = 1250ms   1.25s
sort_students = 9953ms   9.953s
alpha_pass = 7937ms   7.937s
pass_fail = 8359ms   8.359s

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
i7-3770K@3.5GHz - STATIC VECTOR ( 10,000 students =  46.675 secs )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
gen_students = 2184ms   2.184s
sort_students = 32713ms   32.713s
alpha_pass = 5164ms   5.164s
pass_fail = 6614ms   6.614s



-------------------------------------------------------------------------
AMD Opteron 170 - STATIC LIST ( 10,000 students =  32.515 secs )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
gen_students = 890ms   0.89s
sort_students = 15875ms   15.875s
alpha_pass = 7765ms   7.765s
pass_fail = 7985ms   7.985s

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
i7-3770K@3.5GHz - STATIC LIST ( 10,000 students =  27.221 secs )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
gen_students = 374ms   0.374s
sort_students = 17160ms   17.16s
alpha_pass = 4633ms   4.633s
pass_fail = 5054ms   5.054s



-------------------------------------------------------------------------
AMD Opteron 170 - VECTOR ( 10,000 students =  552.094 secs )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
gen_students = 1235ms   1.235s
sort_students = 534765ms   534.765s
alpha_pass = 7750ms   7.75s
pass_fail = 8344ms   8.344s

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
i7-3770K@3.5GHz - VECTOR ( 10,000 students =  896.07 secs )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
gen_students = 2200ms   2.2s
sort_students = 882435ms   882.435s
alpha_pass = 4696ms   4.696s
pass_fail = 6739ms   6.739s



-----------------------------------------------------------
AMD Opteron 170 - LIST ( 10,000 students =  787.984 secs )
-----------------------------------------------------------
gen_students = 906ms   0.906s
sort_students = 771422ms   771.422s
alpha_pass = 7844ms   7.844s
pass_fail = 7812ms   7.812s

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
i7-3770K@3.5GHz - LIST ( 10,000 students =  398.645 secs )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
gen_students = 358ms   0.358s
sort_students = 388412ms   388.412s
alpha_pass = 4758ms   4.758s
pass_fail = 5117ms   5.117s
```

Comment: are you optimizing when compiling?

Comment: Also, were they compiled with the same toolkit+version?

Comment: Show us the benchmarking code :-)

Comment: Also, were they run on the same operating system, and were the other physical parts (namely HD and RAM) the same?  Even when you aren't loading _data_ from the HD, it can have surprising effects on code.

Comment: I'm also surprised at your static-vector vs vector performance, and vector vs list.  There's no way the vector should be closer to list than a static-vector.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains insufficient information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: How do I check if compiling is optimized?...But would this effect a runtime timer? Old cpu(VS2010) New cpu(VS2013). Both win7. All hardware is different, the new PC is much more powerful in all respects.  As for the question being off-topic, don't be silly you would need physical access to both my PCs to 'reproduce the problem' ;)

Comment: @tuk: By default (with VS), builds in the 'Debug' configuration are unoptimized, and builds in the 'Release' configuration are optimized. If you show us the code there's a good chance we can figure out why you're getting these results, without us needing to reproduce them exactly using your hardware.

Comment: @Cameron ...not going to be easy posting the code here, unless there is a way to upload the entire project?

Comment: There is one more clue: when the code is running on the new cpu only a small percentage of the cpu is being used even though 'affinity' is set to use all 7 cores.

Comment: @tuk we are not here to play a guessing game. This question is off topic as it does not provide a clear problem; what you have tried to solve it, and most importantly the code affected.

Comment: @Mgetz Please ask a friend to proof read your post & edit - as per the rules.

Comment: His post actually makes perfect sense - please add at least some description of the code. Is it even multithreaded? Is it doing several passes over the same data? Does the time ratio scale with the problem size? what is the problem size (10k elements of *what*?). There's so much data missing here that there's no point in even trying to think about this.

Comment: sorry Leeor, it seems the mods don't want you to know if its multi threaded or if it re-passes the same code as they've deleted my reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Opteron 170 (older) computer has twice the Level-2 cache of the newer one, which would have a large effect on a very memory-intense operation.   The cache effect would be most pronounced when two items being accesses are near each other --- as they would with a vector --- which is exactly what we are seeing here.

Comment: Would this also explain the newer cpu showing very low usage(<10%) during execution...as cache is effectively being bottlenecked?

Comment: I find this very hard to believe. The Core i7 has a larger L3 cache - which given such a generation difference is probably faster than the L2 of the Opteron.